# telerik get filtered rows radGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik

Ive got radGridView with paging on. I also have separate export to excel button which exports all filtered rows to the excel (all rows not the ones only visible on the current page)

After exporting rows to excel I would like to change for each exported row value in its column "exported" to true. What is the best way to achieve that ?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have a filtered database query like this

```
select 
    field1,
    field2
from table where field1 like 'filter'
```

You could perform the same query, instead of a where clause, select a 0 or 1 using the same logic

```
select 
    field1, 
    field2, 
    case when field1 like 'filter' 
        then 1 
        else 0 
    as wasexported 
from table
```